# How read with xQuery several similar nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Let's imagine I have an XML with the following structure:

```
<book>
 <title>My car is red</title>
 <author>Jhon Doe</author>
 <date>05-21-2021</date>
 <illustration>
    <name>front.jpg</name>
 </illustration>
 <illustration>
    <name>back.jpg</name>
 </illustration>
</book>
```

The  node is repeated several times.
With a xQuery I can read all nodes :

```
for $book in /book
 let $title := $book/title
 let $author := $book/author
return
 ....
```

But I want extract from XML file the name of the two illustration.

I try whit the following code:

```
for $illustration in $book/illustration
let $nombre := $illustration/name
```

But only read the name of the last node

How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Your code generally looks good to me, but it's hard to diagnose the problem since your code is partial. Could you provide (1) a complete expression, (2) the actual results you're getting, and (3) the results you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a nested loop for the illustration.

```
for $book in /book
    let $title := $book/title
    let $author := $book/author
    for $illustration in $book/illustration
        let $nombre := $illustration/name
        return ...
```